# « Quand elle a eu fini » - pourquoi on utilise le passé composé et pas l'imparfait?

Tags: participe-passé, passé-composé, imparfait

La phrase dans le titre vient de « L'Étranger », [ici](https://www.ac-orleans-tours.fr/fileadmin/user_upload/lettres/EAF_Doublants/Etranger/Etranger_texte_3.pdf). Peut-être je ne vois pas quelque chose evident, mais je ne comprends pas la construction là. Je pense qu'il veut dire

> "when she was finished"

ou

> "when she finished"

donc, je penserais qu'on peut dire

> « quand elle était fini ».

C'est à dire: pourquoi est-ce que l'auxiliaire est déjà dans le passé composé et pas l'imparfait?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Elle a eu fini" est une construction de ***[temps surcomposé](https://bescherelle.ca/les-temps-surcomposes/)***.

> Le temps surcomposé est un temps dans lequel le verbe est conjugué avec un double auxiliaire : on ajoute un auxiliaire de plus à un temps déjà composé. Autrement dit, au lieu de laisser l’auxiliaire à un temps simple, on le conjugue au temps composé correspondant.

De la même source :

> On emploie un temps surcomposé lorsque l’on mentionne **un fait ayant eu lieu immédiatement avant** celui dont au parle au temps composé correspondant.

Dans ce contexte, l'idée est donc d'insister sur le fait que la personne vient juste de finir ce qu'elle était en train de faire, et qu'elle a immédiatement effectué une autre action.

Comment: Merci! C'est logique, même si un petit peu bizarre (au moins, pour moi à mon niveau).