# Y a-t-il autant de temps simples que de temps composés ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Dans un questionnaire à choix multiple (QCM) de mon fils (**5e**) j'ai vu la question :

*Coche la phrase vraie.*

1. Les temps composés s'utilisent pour des actions achevées.
2. Les temps composés sont tous constitués de l'auxiliaire avoir et d'un participe passé.
3. Le participe passé peut s'accorder avec le COD antéposé.
4. Il y a autant de temps simples que de temps composés.
5. Le participe passé s'accorde toujours avec le sujet.

Je crois que 3 et 4 sont toutes deux correctes. Mon Bescherelle comporte autant des temps simples que de temps composés. Or, l'énoncé indique de cocher une seule réponse. Y a-t-il une faute ici ?

Comment: Ici, on dirait qu'il y a un temps composé de plus (car le conditionnel possède 2 formes passées) : http://www.conjuguetamere.com/temps-conjugaison Ceci étant, pour un exercice de niveau 5e, je pense que l'idée était juste de dire qu'à l'indicatif, il y a un temps composé associé à chaque temps simple. Auquel cas l'affirmation 4. est aussi vraie que la 3.

Comment: @Reyedy Merci pour votre commentaire ! Personnellement, je crois que cette affirmation est un peu ambiguë:-!)

Comment: Je suis bien d'accord :)

Comment: Il y a beaucoup plus de temps composés que de temps simples si on inclut les temps surcomposés, trop souvent ignorés. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_surcompos%C3%A9

Comment: @jlliagre Merci. Je le sais. Mais mon Bescherelle n'en parle pas ; sans faute de ma part. De plus,c'est sûr qu'en 5e (la classe de mon fils) il ne les ont pas vus.

Comment: @jlliagre Le Guide grammaire Nathan en parle. Je crois qu'un prof du FLE que j'ai eu, m'ai dit qu'ils sont considérés régionalismes. Peut-être je me trompe:-)!

Comment: Bescherelle: https://bescherelle.ca/les-temps-surcomposes/

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41935/quand-elle-a-eu-fini-pourquoi-on-utilise-le-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9-et-pas-limparfa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans mon Bescherelle, *La conjugaison*, j'ai :

- Indicatif

  - simple : (4 temps)

    - présent
    - imparfait
    - passé simple
    - futur
  - composé : (4 temps)

    - passé composé
    - plus-que-parfait
    - passé antérieur
    - futur antérieur
- conditionnel

  - simple : (1 temps)

    - présent
  - composé : (2 temps)

    - passé 1ère forme
    - passé 2ème forme (peu usité)
- subjonctif

  - simple : (2 temps)

    - présent
    - imparfait
  - composé : (2 temps)

    - passé
    - plus-que-parfait
- impératif

  - simple : (1 temps)

    - présent
  - composé : (1 temps)

    - passé
- Infinitif

  - simple : (1 temps)

    - présent
  - composé : (1 temps)

    - passé
- Participe :

  - simple : (2 temps)

    - présent
    - passé
  - composé : (1 temps)

    - passé
- Gérondif :

  - simple : (1 temps)

    - présent
  - composé : (1 temps)

    - passé

Un rapide calcul donne donc (revu et corrigé, merci @jlliagre) :

- 12 temps simples
- 12 temps composés

On a autant de temps composés que de temps simples.

---

Cependant, il existe également des [temps surcomposés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_surcompos%C3%A9) au nombre d'un vingtaine, ces temps entrent bien évidemment dans la catégorie des temps composés.

On a finalement bien plus de temps composés que de temps simples.

Comment: Apparement, tu as raison. Mon ancien Bescherelle donne explicitement les deux formes du conditionnel passé. Le plus recent, que j'ai consulté, donne la deuxième forme comme NB. Mais , pourquoi les deux formes doivent être considérées comme des deux temps différents ? Ça je ne comprends pas.

Comment: Il faut qu'on mette en avant que la question s'adresse à une classe du collège (5e).

Comment: @Dimitris: Le conditionnel passé 2ème forme est très peu utilisé, principalement dans les œuvres littéraires, rarement, voire exceptionnellement, dans le langage parlé. Il a tendance à tomber en désuétude. PS Mon Bescherelle date de 1990

Comment: Merci. Les miens datent de 1978 et de 2004. Selon le Guide grammaire "Le Robert&Nathan" (paragraph 664) que j'ai consulté ayant lu ta réponse, les deux formes ont la même valeur. Pour cette raison je t'ai posé la question pourquoi on doit les compter pour deux temps différents. De toute façon, ta réponse est supère. Je ne peux pas dire la même chose pour l'affirmation de la question du QCM de mon fils qui me paraît ambiguë.

Comment: @Dimitris: C'est certain que la question est ambiguë, de plus, quel en est l'intérêt

Comment: Il faudrait rajouter l'infinitif, le participe et le gérondif à la liste. Ils ont chacun un présent toujours simple et un passé toujours composé sauf pour le participe qui deux passés, un simple et un composé...

Comment: @jlliagre: Merci, correction effectuée.

Comment: Tu pourrais aussi tenir compte de ce commentaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41938/y-a-t-il-autant-de-temps-simples-que-de-temps-compos%c3%a9s#comment85349_41938 Les temps surcomposés existent et la question ne précise pas s'il faut que les temps soient enseignés ou utilisés partout.

Comment: @jlliagre: Certes, mais ils sont vraiment très peu usités et la question porte sur un QCM donné à son fils qui est en 5ème.

Comment: J'ai bien compris que la question fait référence à un QCM destiné à des élèves de 5e mais on peut affirmer sans prendre de risque que la grande majorité des lecteurs de ta réponse ne fera pas partie de cette population de collégiens et s'attendra à une réponse exhaustive. Qu'ils soient en odeur de sainteté ou pas, les temps surcomposés qui font partie de la littérature et qui sont encore employés par certains francophones, en tout cas plus que l'imparfait du subjonctif, ne devraient pas être frappés d'ostracisme...

Comment: Tu pourrais par exemple terminer ta réponse par *voire plus si l'on tient compte des temps surcomposés*.