# Lorsqu'elle a eu / avait / a terminé, nous nous sommes assises

Tags: verbes, passé-composé, temps-composés, plus-que-parfait

Bonjour,

*Roses de sans Roses d'Ouessant* de Janine Boissard :

> Elle a choisi un vélo dans l'appentis : le plus grand, avec une
> barre. Son propriétaire - devinez qui - aurait été flatté. (...)
> Morgane a sorti ses appareils et elle a mitraillé les lieux. (...)
>
> Lorsqu'elle **a eu terminé**, nous **nous sommes assises** dans un coin à peu
> près sec et nous **avons discuté** du héros de notre histoire.

Pourquoi l'auteure emploie "a eu terminé" ici ? Ça ne devrait pas être "avait terminé" ? Ou en raison de "lorsque", "a terminé" ?

Comment: Il semble que « l'apprentis » devrait être  « l'ppentis ».

Comment: @LPH Oui, merci, j'ajoute souvent des lettres ! Je vais corriger.

Comment: J'allais répondre quand j'ai vu que la question était déjà posée. "a eu terminé"  est le passé antérieur surcomposé. De toutes façons le plus-que-parfait (avait terminé) n'était pas possible vu qu'il s'agit d'une action ponctuelle.

Comment: @None Merci pour le lien. _On emploie un temps surcomposé lorsque l’on mentionne un fait ayant eu lieu immédiatement avant celui dont au parle au temps composé correspondant._ _Du reste, les temps surcomposés, fréquemment employés par les gens de lettres jusqu’au XVIIIe siècle, ont perdu leur vitalité aujourd’hui._  // Pourquoi le plus-que-parfait ne convient pas ? _​​Le plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif sert souvent à exprimer une action qui a eu lieu avant une autre dans le passé._ [Alloprof](https://www.alloprof.qc.ca/fr/eleves/bv/francais/le-plus-que-parfait-de-l-indicatif-f1201)

Comment: @None Exemples de cette source : 
    _Mon copain a adoré les poèmes que j'**avais écrits** pendant ma jeunesse.
    Elle me demandait constamment de lui prêter les bijoux que ma mère m'**avait donnés**.
    Elle devint très bouleversée quand elle constata qu'il **était déjà parti**._

Comment: Dans les phrases que tu cites les actions au plus-que-parfait sont terminés depuis un temps plus ou moins longs par rapport aux actions au passé composé, on ne pourrait pas employer lorsque. **Lorsque** ici indique une quasi simultanéité avec une toute petite antériorité. Quelques pistes: https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/plus-que-parfait-l-expression-de-l-anteriorite-grammaire-b1/ et https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/quand-et-lorsque-deux-marqueurs-temporels-particuliers-grammaire-b1/.

Comment: Et dans la [réponse à la question signalée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/41936/358) c'est bien dit (et c'est exact) : "On emploie un temps surcomposé lorsque l’on mentionne un fait ayant eu lieu immédiatement avant celui dont au parle au temps composé correspondant."

Answer (score 1):

Non, l'imparfait à une valeur de temps continuatif (aussi appelé duratif) ou répétitif. Ici, le passé surcomposé insiste sur l'aspect accompli.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l%27indicatif_en_fran%C3%A7ais)) L'imparfait présente l'action dans son déroulement, en cours d'accomplissement ou répétée durant un moment du passé connu de tous les participants à l'échange linguistique, même s'il s'agit d'une connaissance tacite.

Voilà un contexte où l'imparfait conviendrait. On transforme l'action, et au lieu de la considérer comme une occurrence unique on la présente comme une action habituelle, qui était plus ou moins régulièrement répétée.

- C'est ainsi que nous passions nos après-midi ; elle choisissait un vélo dans l'appentis : le plus grand, avec une barre. Son propriétaire - devinez qui - en était flatté. (...)
  Lorsqu'elle avait  terminé sa promenade, nous nous asseyions dans un coin à peu près sec et nous discutions du héros de notre histoire.

La conjonction « lorsque » n'a rien à voir dans le choix du temps.

Voilà un autre contexte où l'auteur considère l'action de « terminer » selon l'aspect duratif parce cette sorte d'action prend du temps. On peut, en choisissant l'aspect, montrer soit l'un soit l'autre des deux procès.

- Elle a choisi un vélo dans l'appentis : le plus grand, avec une barre. Son propriétaire - devinez qui - aurait été flatté. (...) Morgane a sorti ses appareils et elle a mitraillé les lieux. (...)
  Lorsqu'elle terminait et remettait ses appareils dans leurs sacoches, il y a eu une petite explosion ; c'était une des batteries de ses appareils qui était défectueuse.

L'action est vue comme quelque chose qui dure, c'est peut-être le petit moment pendant lequel les appareil sont placés dans leur housses ou sacs. C'est pour montrer cela que l'on utilise l'imparfait. Dans sa phrase, Boissard ne choisit pas l'imparfait parce qu'il ne s'agit ni d'une action habituelle ni d'une action qui dure. Elle n'a pas dans l'idée de signifier une période finale mais seulement la fin elle-même en tant que point après lequel l'action n'est plus du tout poursuivie.

Comment: Lorsque a **tout** à voir avec l'emploi du passé antérieur surcomposé de la question. Et dans la concordance des temps l'aspect duratif de l'imparfait n'est pas vraiment en question.

Comment: @None  Il s'agit du **passé composé surcomposé** (Indicatif passé composé → Indicatif passé surcomposé :   j'ai envoyé, j'ai été envoyé → j'ai eu envoyé, j'ai eu été envoyé ) ; ensuite, non, « lorsque » ne gouverne pas l'emploi d'un temps particulier.  ex : Lorsqu'elle sera arrivée,  Lorsqu'il viendra, Lorsqu'ils avaient le temps, Lorsqu'il eu donné le feu vert, Lorsqu'on aura eu l'opportunité, Lorsqu'ils avaient été découverts, Lorsqu'il l'a eu terminée etc.

Comment: Lorsque :https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/quand-et-lorsque-deux-marqueurs-temporels-particuliers-grammaire-b1/

Comment: @None Il n'y a pas de problème, tous les temps de l'indicatif (temps, simultanéité et postériorité) et rarement le conditionnel (condition). Il y a seulement un concordance a respecter selon l'aspect et dans la phrase examinée elle est correcte parce que l'aspect ne peut être que de l'aspect accompli.